# Angularjs ui-grid load the columns lazily

Tags: angularjs, grid, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Is there any way to load the columns lazily. I've a set of 5k columns and 100k rows. I'm using `angularjs 1.5.7` and `angular-ui-grid ^3.x`.

The grid works perfect with 100k rows and 100 columns. But if I tried to load more than 2k columns it takes 10-15 sec to load the page. I'm using infinite scroll module.

It would be great if there is any way to load the columns lazily on demand. Or anyway to extend the ui-grid library.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the config option columnVirtualizationThreshold to the number of columns of my table:

```
columnVirtualizationThreshold: $scope.columns.length
```

Only problem is the issue that the vertical scrolling becomes slower.
See this thread: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/2784